# Telegram бот на Java

Tags: java, telegram-bot, telegram, бот

Подскажите, есть Telegram бот написанный на Java, использую официальное **API**, также же имеется **БД** с `chatID` *(ID-пользователей)* данного бота.

Есть задумка отправить всем подписчикам бота общее сообщение использовав их chatID. Кто подскажет как это реализовать?